# Magic sum with binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Mathematica gives to me the following relation for every fixed $m,n\geq1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {(2n-k-1)!\cdot k}{(n-k)!} {{m+k}\choose{m}} =\frac{(m+1)(m+2n)!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Any hint for the proof?

Comment: This is just an instance of Vandermonde's identity. You may also immediately remove the term $n!$ from both sides.

Comment: How can you interpret it as a  Vandermonde's identity? The  Vandermonde's identity that I know is ${{m+n}\choose{r}}=\sum_{k=0}^r{{m}\choose{k}}{{n}\choose{r-k}}.$ How can I reconduce my formula to this form? Do I need the exended version for complex numbers (Chu-Vandermonde identity)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n}&\color{blue}{\frac{(2n-k-1)!k}{n!(n-k)!}\binom{m+k}{m}}\\
> &=\frac{m+1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n-1-k}{n-k}\binom{m+k}{k-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{m+1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{-n}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-m-2}{k-1}(-1)^{k-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{m+1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{-n}{n-1-k}\binom{-m-2}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{m+1}{n}\binom{-n-m-2}{n-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{m+1}{n}\binom{m+2n}{n-1}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(m+1)(m+2n)!}{n!(m+n+1)!}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the factorials using binomial coefficients and use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p-q}{q}\binom{p}{q-1}$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we shift the index by one to start with $k=0$.
- In (4) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.
- In (5) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ again.